# Publishing virtual camera images from RVIZ

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

is it possible to define some kind of virtual camera model in the 3d world of rviz, where the video stream or single images can be published and therefore processed by successive ros nodes?

With best regards,

Marc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142351/publishing-virtual-camera-images-from-rviz/) by [MZofka](https://answers.ros.org/users/8236/mzofka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-31**:
Do you want to use that for visualization/presentation purposes or to run vision algorithms based on that?

**Comment by [MZofka](https://answers.ros.org/users/8236/mzofka/) on 2014-03-31**:
Hi, thank you for your fast response. I want to run vision algorithms, like segmentation on that simulated camera view.

With best regards,
Marc

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-03-31**:
That sounds like you want a simulation like gazebo that does this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rviz_camera_stream](https://github.com/lucasw/rviz_camera_stream) publishes an image rendered in rviz.  It builds in jade at least, but likely works in hydro and indigo, and following the fork back leads to a pre-catkin version.

It needs an input camera_info to get camera intrinsics and resolution.  The distortion coefficients are ignored, but a image_proc like node that implements http://code.opencv.org/issues/1387 could address that downstream.  (Do gazebo cameras support distortion yet? http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=camera_distortion says version 5.0 does)

The input camera_info topic and output image topic are set in the rviz plugin gui.

Old suggestion:

One hacky solution is to run a screen grab node http://wiki.ros.org/screengrab_ros and position the rviz window just so, though it would be very brittle and hard to automate with launch files.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2